# Adobe air multiple apps in one installer

Tags: air, installation

Is there a way to install more then one air application with single installer?

Comment: I have the same requirement, no solution yet either.

Comment: To elaborate further: could I define more than 1 AIR app in .airinstall.cfg to install 2 apps in a single Sidecar Installation? If someone has prototyped this successfully, it's a solution.

Comment: This isn't a solution but a work around, as per the example [here](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/08/adobe-air-distribution-and-installation/) you can use an alternate installer like InstallJammer and tell it to install 2 or more AIR apps and sidecar installations in single packaged installer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3rd party tool like InstallShield, I think That will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Defining several entries in `.airinstall.cfg` will not work, either by having AIR app entries on a single line, separating by comma etc. Installer fails to launch, at least on Mac OS X.